# How do I remove whitespace from the end of a string in Python?

Tags: python

I need to remove whitespaces after the word in the string. Can this be done in one line of code?

Example:

```
string = "    xyz     "

desired result : "    xyz"
```

Comment: @Greg K Yes, because even those who've read the docs might not realize it may be there, seeing as it is a fundamental that they may have tuned out the first few times they read it, and remember it as saying something unrelated. Plus, rstrip in the docs doesn't show up easily in a Google search for this problem (using the criteria 'python strip end of string').

Comment: real cold @GregK real cold

Comment: It also adds to the general unfriendliness which is sadly becoming increasingly characteristic of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes it had to be asked.  I googled how to do it and I ended up here.  I didn't immediately start searching the python library.  If all we do is ask google/bing/etc then we stop communicating with each other as people.

Answer (score 240, accepted):

```
>>> "    xyz     ".rstrip()
'    xyz'
```

There is more about `rstrip` in [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip).

Answer (score 18):

You can use strip() or split() to control the spaces values as the following,
and here is some test functions:

```
words = "   test     words    "

# Remove end spaces
def remove_end_spaces(string):
    return "".join(string.rstrip())

# Remove first and  end spaces
def remove_first_end_spaces(string):
    return "".join(string.rstrip().lstrip())

# Remove all spaces
def remove_all_spaces(string):
    return "".join(string.split())

# Remove all extra spaces
def remove_all_extra_spaces(string):
    return " ".join(string.split())

# Show results
print(f'"{words}"')
print(f'"{remove_end_spaces(words)}"')
print(f'"{remove_first_end_spaces(words)}"')
print(f'"{remove_all_spaces(words)}"')
print(f'"{remove_all_extra_spaces(words)}"')
```

output:

```
"   test     words    "

"   test     words"

"test     words"

"testwords"

"test words"
```

i hope this helpful .

Comment: It's unnecessary to use `rstrip()` and `lstrip()` when there's a specific function that does both: `strip()`

Comment: Oh, I see you rejected my edit and then did it yourself. Seems that `This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive.` wasn't true after all.