# Removal of white space

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get rid of the white space at the end of each line.

```
w = input("Words: ")
w = w.split()
k = 1
length = []
for ws in w:
  length.append(len(ws))
  y = sorted(length)
while k <= y[-1]:
  if k in length:
    for ws in w:
      if len(ws) != k:
        continue
      else:
        print(ws, end=" ")
    print("")
  k += 1
```

The out put is giving me lines of words in assessing lengths eg if I type in I do love QI;
I
do QI
love

But it has white space at the end of each line. If I try to .rstrip() it I also delete the spaces between the words and get;
I
doQI
love

Comment: string.rstrip() would work for you.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372573/how-do-i-remove-whitespace-from-the-end-of-a-string-in-python

Comment: ^ Nope. Based on the OP's below comment "I have tried this but I keep losing the space between the words that are listed on the line." I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739909/how-to-strip-all-whitespace-from-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use " ".join(ws) instead and it will auto but them on the same line (you will need to create a list rather than a string)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `rstrip`
demo:

```
>>> 'hello '.rstrip()
'hello'
```

`rstrip` removes any whitespace from right

`lstrip` removes whitespace from left:

```
>>> '  hello '.lstrip()
'hello '
```

while `strip` removes from both end:

```
>>> '  hello '.strip()
'hello'
```

you need to use split to convert them to list

```
>>> "hello,how,are,you".split(',')    # if ',' is the delimiter
['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you']
>>> "hello how are you".split()       # if whitespace is delimiter
['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you']
```

Comment: I have tried this but I keep losing the space between the words that are listed on the line.

Comment: I want it to list - I, do qi, love and when I rstrip it it reads I, doqi, love

Comment: can you show what is your input and expected output??

Comment: you need to use split not strip

Comment: @user3864194: You need to use rstrip() on the input data __before__ you split it into words.

Answer (score 0):

```
re.sub(r"[ ]*$","",x)
```

You use use `re.sub` of `re` module.

Comment: You _could_, but why use regex for a problem that a builtin str method can handle?

Comment: From doing some reading I think this will work but Im not sure where to put it in context of my code?

Comment: @user3864194 x is a line which you pass.just put it in a loop and pass lines.return value would be line without spaces at end