# Removing whitespace from the end of string while keeping space in the middle of each letter

Tags: python, python-3.x

The goal of this code is to take a bunch of letters and print the first letter and every third letter after that for the user. What's the easiest way to remove the whitespace at the end of the output here while keeping all the spaces in the middle?

```
msg = input('Message? ')
for i in range(0, len(msg), 3):
  print(msg[i], end = ' ')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove whitespace from the end of a string in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372573/how-do-i-remove-whitespace-from-the-end-of-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

[`str_object.rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) will return a copy of `str_object` without trailing whitespace. Just do

```
msg = input('Message? ').rstrip()
```

For what it's worth, you can replace your loop by string slicing:

```
print(*msg[::3], sep=' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n = '   hello  '
n.rstrip()
'   hello'
n.lstrip()
'hello   '
n.strip()
'hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

What about?

```
msg = input('Message? ')
output = ' '.join(msg[::3]).rstrip()
print(output)
```

Comment: I want to keep a space between all of the letters though. Only removing the whitespace after the least letter

Comment: @CianMcGovern Edited, take a look

Answer (score 0):

You can use at least 2 methods:

1) Slicing method:

```
    print(" ".join(msg[0::3]))
```

2) List comprehension (more readable/powerful):

```
    print(" ".join([letter for i,letter in enumerate(msg) if i%3==0])
```